# Have Excel switch to next row if first row is populated

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning Excel VBA and I just hit a wall.

I have a spreadsheet in which I built a UserForm. This userform populates Row 14 from A to AK.

Now I've been able to copy the data from the form using this code (part of it it's way to long to copy completely here):

```
'Date
Sheet1.Range("A14") = DTPicker1
'AC Type
Sheet1.Range("b14") = ComboBox1
'AC Reg
Sheet1.Range("C14") = TextBox3
'Pic
Sheet1.Range("d14") = TextBox5
'co-pilot
Sheet1.Range("e14") = TextBox4
'from
Sheet1.Range("f14") = TextBox7
'to
Sheet1.Range("g14") = TextBox6
'remarks
Sheet1.Range("h14") = TextBox8
```

Now what I would like to do is that IF A14 is populated, well everything that writes in 14 switches to 15, and so on.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work (untested):

```
Static rng As Range
If rng Is Nothing Then
  Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A14")
  Do While rng.Value <> ""
     Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
  Loop
End If

'Date
rng.Range("A1").Value = DTPicker1
'AC Type
rng.Range("B1").Value = ComboBox1
'AC Reg
rng.Range("C1").Value = TextBox3
'Pic
rng.Range("D1").Value = TextBox5
'co-pilot
rng.Range("E1").Value = TextBox4
'from
rng.Range("F1").Value = TextBox7
'to
rng.Range("G1").Value = TextBox6
'remarks
rng.Range("H1").Value = TextBox8

'Point to the next line
Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
```

Comment: As an aside - one thing I like to do in cases like this is to use a named range for your first cell.  This can be done by highlighting the cell you want to start with (in this case, `A14`), and going to Formulas->Name Manager.  Then click "New", and give the cell a name in the "Name" text box (e.g. `StartingPoint`).  Then you can change the line at the top to `Set rng = Sheet1.Range("StartingPoint")`.  This makes it easier to maintain when you (inevitably) have to mess around with the design of the  Excel form... all you have to do is update the cell reference, rather than changing code.